# How to push an array into an array using reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing an app that removes duplicates from an array of arguments. I was able to figure out how to remove them, but it works only if the elements of the arguments array are numbers not arrays themselves:

```
function unite() {
  var args = [].concat.apply([], arguments);

  return args.reduce(function(result, current){
    return result.indexOf(current) === -1  ? result.concat(current) : result;
  }, []);
}
```

This code:

```
unite([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 4, 4], [2, 1]);
```

returns [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]

whereas this one:

```
unite([1, 3, 2], [5, [7], 4, 4], [2, 1]);
```

returns [1, 3, 2, 5, **7**, 4]

I need it to return
[1, 3, 2, 5, **[7]**, 4]

What is a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Do your arrays need to be checked for duplicates as well? E.g. should `unite([1, 3, 2], [5, [7], 4, 4], [2, 1, [7]]);` return `[1, 3, 2, 5, [7], 4]` or `[1, 3, 2, 5, [7], 4, [7]]`?

Comment: They should be treated as numbers, so the first one applies.

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice` rather than `concat` first (`concat` will flatten the array to one level above) and then iterate over each `current` item in `reduce` to check if there is a duplicate.

**DEMO**

```js
function unite() {
  var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);

  return args.reduce(function(result, current){
    //console.log(result, current)
    current.forEach( function(item){ result.indexOf( item ) == -1 && result.push( item ); }) ;
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log( unite([1, 3, 2], [5, [7], 4, 4], [2, 1]) );
```

If you need to remove duplicate array then you need to iterate and check for array equality as well.

**DEMO**

```js
function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) 
{
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) 
    {
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
        {
            if ( !( Array.isArray( arr1[i] ) && Array.isArray( arr2[i] ) && arraysEqual(arr1[i], arr2[i] ) ) )
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function unite() {
  var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);

  return args.reduce(function(result, current){
    //console.log(result, current)
    current.forEach( function(item){ 
       if ( Array.isArray ( item ) )
       {
           result.filter( function( res ){
              return Array.isArray ( res ) && arraysEqual( item, res ); 
           }).length == 0 && result.push( item );
       }
       else
       {
          result.indexOf( item ) == -1 && result.push( item ); 
       }
    }) ;
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log( unite([1, 3, 2], [5, [7], 4, 4], [2, 1, [7]]) );
```

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks for helping. The second works fine! I need some more time to understand how it all works :)

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `result.concat(current)` will be appended to `result`. If the argument is an array, its elements will be appended. So - in order to append an array - you need to supply an array of array:

```js
function unite() {
  var args = [].concat.apply([], arguments);

  return args.reduce(function(result, current) {
    return result.indexOf(current) === -1 ? result.concat([current]) : result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(unite([1, 2], [2, 3], [[7]], [[7]]));
```

A faster way to implement the same functionality is:

```js
function* iterate(...arrays) {
  for (array of arrays) yield* array;
}

function unite(...arrays) {
  return Array.from(new Set(iterate(...arrays)));
}

console.log(unite([1, 2], [2, 3], [[7]], [[7]]));
```

Both implementations treat two arrays containing identical elements as different (according to JavaScript's object equality semanics).